# How to style the container of a jQuery Select2 combo box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

Is it possible to style the combo box **container** using the Select2 jQuery plugin? I can successfully style the **dropdown** menu where autocomplete selections appear, but not the container where text is entered. Here's what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#combo").select2({
        data:[{id:0,text:'One'},{id:1,text:'Two'}],
        multiple: true,
        createSearchChoice: function (term) {
            return { id: term, text: term };
        },
        containerCss: 'container',
        dropdownCssClass: 'dropdown',
        containerCss: {
            background: 'green'   
        }
    });
});

<input type="hidden" id="combo" style="width:350px" />

#combo {
    background: green;
}
.container {
    background: green;
}
.dropdown {
    background: red;
}
```

The container should be green, but it's not. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4vt8jhx/).

**Edit:**
I noticed on the documentation page for the site (which is quite comprehensive) that every example of the kind I'm trying to do (hidden input field with dynamically loaded options) has the same standard style, like in my example fiddle. The version that originates from a select element, however, has rounded corners etc. If this means you can't style the container when using a hidden input, it's seems like an odd limitation.

**Edit2:**
@emmanuel has already provided a solution, but since I was actually after the border-radius, there was a bit more to do to get it working properly. After setting the radius on all corners, opening the dropdown results in rounded corners visible between the top of the dropdown and the bottom of the container, which is a bit ugly. You can do something like this to fix it:

```
$('ul.select2-choices').on("select2-open", function() {
    $('ul.select2-choices').css({
        'border-bottom-left-radius': '0px',
        'border-bottom-right-radius': '0px',
    });
});
$('ul.select2-choices').on("select2-close", function() { 
    $('ul.select2-choices').css({
        'border-bottom-left-radius': '5px', // or whatever
        'border-bottom-right-radius': '5px', // or whatever
    });
});
```

I think this will cause a problem, though, for any other Select2 combo boxes visible on the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add background color to container you have to put the rule to `#s2id_combo`. The problem is that `ul.select2-choices` already has a background and it's over container so you have to add:

```
ul.select2-choices { background: green !important; }
```

Comment: It's actually not the background color I'm interested in, it's the border-radius, but that seems to be working too (no !important necessary).